# This Dapper Query is always returning a null

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc-4, dapper

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Dapper;
namespace Calculate.Models
{
    public class SelectedDetailsGetter
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=CHANDAKG-01-L\\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=Calculator;integrated security=true");
        public IEnumerable<SelectedDetails> GetSelectedDetails(string Name)
        {

            string query = "SELECT * FROM DataNorm WHERE Provider=@name AND year(DateMonth)=2014";
                var result = con.Query<SelectedDetails>(query,new { name = Name });
                return result;
        }
    }
}
```

This Query is always returning a null. Is there something wrong?? And can anyone tell the use of `SingleOrDefault()`

Comment: Does `GetSelectedDetails` return `null` or are you saying that calling `SingleOrDefault` on it returns `null`?

Comment: GetSelectedDetails() returns null..

Comment: Are you passing in actual Provider names into "Name"? If you run that query in SSMS with the Provider = 'whomever', does it return data? I'm assuming that when you don't pass in anything, nothing is returned by the query. Debug the query. See what its producing for "result".Maybe you connection is bad? Also are the props in "SelectedDetails" named the same as the SQL columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, The SingleOrDefault() Function will always return one unique register if exists of course. The people use when the result of a query will return rows more than once, but in this case just the first matters.

Now, the solve of your problem

Always use "using" to work with connections, its the best way to guarantee that you will never forget to close and dispose the opened connection.

You always will need open the conection after instantiating the object Connection.

Try this:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectedDetails> GetSelectedDetails(string Name)
            {
                using (var con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=CHANDAKG-01-L\\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=Calculator;integrated security=true"))
                {
                    con.Open();

                    string query = @"   SELECT * 
                                        FROM DataNorm 
                                        WHERE Provider= @name 
                                          AND year(DateMonth) = 2014 ";

                    var result = con.Query<SelectedDetails>(query, new { name = Name });

                    return result;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Actually if there is more than one result `SingleOrDefault` will throw an exception.  `FirstOrDefault` is what you want to use if you want the first item of possible zero or multiple rows.

Comment: I tried your solution @Gustavo..Its not working..Its still returning NULL..I am connecting to SQL in a method which is called prior to this, there it is working fine and returning the result too..

Answer (score 0):

From [github](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net#execute-a-query-and-map-the-results-to-a-strongly-typed-list):

> Note: all extension methods assume the connection is already open, they will fail if the connection is closed.